# Android Custom Date Picker doesn't call overridden methods

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I have a custom DatePickerDialog that takes two Joda date time objects to set the min/max dates. I want to override the behavior of selecting a date outside of this range so that you can't do it. For some reason the overridden methods **onDateChanged** and **updateDate** are not called, date picker documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html

```
public class CustomDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    DateTime maxDateTime;
    DateTime minDateTime;
    DateTime selectedDateTime;

    public CustomDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, Calendar c, DateTime minDateTime, DateTime maxDateTime) {
        super(context, callBack, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        this.maxDateTime = maxDateTime;
        this.minDateTime = minDateTime;

        getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDateTime.getMillis());
        getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDateTime.getMillis());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "date changed");
        selectedDateTime = new DateTime(year, month + 1, day, 0, 0);

        if (selectedDateTime.getMillis() > maxDateTime.getMillis()) {
            Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "selected date time is greater than");
//            super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
        } else {
            super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        super.onClick(dialog, which);
    }

    @Override
    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return super.getDatePicker();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDate(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Log.d(LogUtil.RANDOM_TAG, "update date");
        super.updateDate(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    }

    @Override
    public Bundle onSaveInstanceState() {
        return super.onSaveInstanceState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }


}
```